# VB.net error BC30516 - Overload resolution failed because no accessible "new" accepts this number of arguments

Tags: vb.net

I tried to declare a public variable in a public module for my form with this code:

```
Public deathSound As New String
```

and later add some info to the variable

```
If weapon = 1 Then
    deathSound = ("My.resources.stone_impact")
End If
```

But all i get is error BC30516 "Overload resolution failed because no accessible "new" accepts this number of arguments", even though i have many more variables with almost identical code that work normally

I am using Visual Studio 2017 btw.

Answer (score 2):

The error message tells you exactly what the problem is. There is no constructor on the `String` class with no parameters. If you have similar code elsewhere then it must be for different types, which do have parameterless constructors, or else you're just declaring the variable without invoking a constructor using `New`.

What point is there to invoking a constructor there in the first place? What do you expect `deathSound` to contain? The only logical options are an empty `String` and `Nothing`. If you want it to be an empty `String` then just declare the variable and assign `String.Empty` to it:

```vb
Public deathSound As String = String.Empty
```

If you expect it to be `Nothing` then just declare the variable and don't assign anything or else explicitly assign `Nothing`:

```vb
Public deathSound As String
```

```vb
Public deathSound As String = Nothing
```

None of those code snippets invoke a constructor because none use the `New` keyword.

In future, you should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation first when you have an issue. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/dotnet/api/system.string.-ctor) is the documentation for the constructors on the `String` class. As you can see, none of them have no parameters. If you check the corresponding documentation for others classes, you'll find that many of them do have parameterless constructors because it makes sense to create an instance that way for those types.